# Trimming Values in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. This database has a table with a column named "Name" whose data is not cleaned up. For instance, there are values like 'Hello    ', where there is unnecessary whitespace. I want to remove that whitespace from all of the values in the "Name" column. My table looks like this:

```
MyTable
-------
ID (int)
Name varchar(50)
Description nvarchar(128)
```

How do I trim up the values in the Name column to remove leading and trailing whitespace?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [`RTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(Name));
```